# Salvar todos os resultados do PHP em uma tabela única em HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, tabela-html

No meu host tem um index.html com um formulário que é ligado á um login.php que pega os resultados que o usuário digitou e salva em uma tabela HTML na raiz do site. O problema é que é criado uma tabela para cada usuário sendo que eu quero que os dados de todos os usuários sejam salvos em uma única tabela. Sou muito novo, pesquisei muito e não consegui resolver. Aqui vai um pedaço do código:

```html
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo'); 
$usuario = $_POST['user_id'];
$senha   = $_POST['password'];
$hora=@date("H:i:s d/m/y");
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
//crie uma variável para receber o código da tabela
    $tabela = '<table border="1">';//abre table
    $tabela .='<thead>';//abre cabeçalho
    $tabela .= '<tr>';//abre uma linha
    $tabela .= '<th>E-mail</th>'; // colunas do cabeçalho
    $tabela .= '<th>Senha</th>';
    $tabela .= '<th>IP</th>';
    $tabela .= '<th>Navegador</th>';
 $tabela .= '<th>Sistema Operacional</th>';
    $tabela .= '<th>Data</th>';
    $tabela .= '</tr>';//fecha linha
    $tabela .='</thead>'; //fecha cabeçalho
    $tabela .='<tbody>';//abre corpo da tabela
    /*Se você tiver um loop para exibir os dados ele deve ficar aqui*/
    $tabela .= '<tr>'; // abre uma linha
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$usuario.'</td>'; // coluna email
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$senha.'</td>'; //coluna senha
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$ip.'</td>'; // coluna ip
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$user_browser.'</td>'; //coluna navegador
 $tabela .= '<td>'.$user_os.'</td>'; //coluna so
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$hora.'</td>';//coluna data
    $tabela .= '</tr>'; // fecha linha
    /*loop deve terminar aqui*/
    $tabela .='</tbody>'; //fecha corpo
    $tabela .= '</table>';//fecha tabela

   $fp = fopen("dados.html", "a");
   fwrite($fp, $tabela
   fclose($fp);
   header("Location: https://meusite.com");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa solução não é a mais indicada, a melhor solução seria armazenar esses dados em um banco de dados e depois ler ele para montar a sua tabela HTML da melhor forma possível.

mas dentro desse cenário acredito que vc pode remover as 2 ultimas tags que indicam o final da tabela, e continuar sua escrita. 
Mas teria que verificar se o arquivo existe para escrever o cabeçalho ou não exemplo:

```
if(!file_exists("dados.html")){
    $tabela = '<table border="1">';//abre table
    $tabela .='<thead>';//abre cabeçalho
    $tabela .= '<tr>';//abre uma linha
    $tabela .= '<th>E-mail</th>'; // colunas do cabeçalho
    $tabela .= '<th>Senha</th>';
    $tabela .= '<th>IP</th>';
    $tabela .= '<th>Navegador</th>';
    $tabela .= '<th>Sistema Operacional</th>';
    $tabela .= '<th>Data</th>';
    $tabela .= '</tr>';//fecha linha
    $tabela .='</thead>'; //fecha cabeçalho
    $tabela .='<tbody>';//abre corpo da tabela
}else{       
   $str=file_get_contents('dados.html');
   preg_replace('\<\/(tbody|table)\>', '', $str);
   file_put_contents('dados.html', $str);
}
$tabela .= '<tr>'; // abre uma linha
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$usuario.'</td>'; // coluna email
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$senha.'</td>'; //coluna senha
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$ip.'</td>'; // coluna ip
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$user_browser.'</td>'; //coluna navegador
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$user_os.'</td>'; //coluna so
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$hora.'</td>';//coluna data
    $tabela .= '</tr>'; // fecha linha
    /*loop deve terminar aqui*/
    $tabela .='</tbody>'; //fecha corpo
    $tabela .= '</table>';//fecha tabela

   $fp = fopen("dados.html", "a");
   fwrite($fp, $tabela
   fclose($fp);
   header("Location: https://meusite.com");
```

Comment: Perfeito amigo! Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!

Comment: A solução adequada depende de cada caso. Há casos que são bastante óbvios, mas esse apresentado não pois, não se sabe qual a finalidade de salvar o html dessa forma. Por isso, é irrelevante dizer que o adequado seria usar banco de dados.